# Does a Protean Scourge's simulacrum retain the ability to split up and recombine?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, monsters, simulacrum

The simulacrum has less HD than the original creature, but to what extent does it retain the original creature's abilities?

The Protean Scourge (*Monster Manual III*, p. 126) has the ***Split*** ability the beginning of which says:

> ***Split*** (Su): When damaged, a protean scourge splits into two identical versions of itself [...]

Can the Protean Scourge's simulacrum be split up and recombine?

Answer (score 0):

### The DM must decide, but likely not

Like in your other question, the relevant part of the [simulacrum](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/simulacrum.htm) spell says:

> It appears to be the same as the original, but **it has only one-half of the real creature’s** levels or **Hit Dice (and the appropriate** hit points, feats, skill ranks, and **special abilities for a creature of that level or HD**).

So your DM needs to decide how strong the ability is, and if it would be *appropriate* for a creature with only half the hit dice of a protean scourge.

The protean scourge is a 13 HD monster with a challenge rating of
12. Other CR 12 creatures include for example the [Cyclops](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Cyclops_(3.5e_Creature)), that has more hit dice (17 vs 13), and also has better AC (27 vs 23), better to hit (+23 vs +18) and better damage (3d8+18 vs 2d6+5) than the scourge. Why is that? One can explain why by realizing that part of what makes the scourges dangerous comes not from HD, AC, to hit and damage, but from its special qualities like its spellcasting and the ability to split or change shape -- the cyclops has few elaborate special qualities in comparison, and makes up for it with better base values. So these abilities seem to be pretty strong.

That means, when you half the scourge's HD, you should also review its special qualities, so it still is in line with other monsters of 6 HD. What would be appropriate for such a creature?

The split ability says:

> Split (Su): **When damaged, a protean scourge splits into two identical versions** of itself. This ability is not an illusion; each new protean scourge is fully capable of dealing real damage and poses a real threat. Each version of the protean scourge has all the current statistics and access to all the current abilities of a single creature, including any
> remaining uncast spells. However, any spells cast by either
> split protean scourge come from the total pool of remaining
> available spells. [...] **Each version has the protean scourge’s current hit point total (they do not split remaining hit points)**, and both versions of the protean scourge must be slain to kill the creature. [...]

Let's compare this with another creature of 6HD that has a split ability, the [Ochre Jelly](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Ochre_Jelly). This one says:

> **Split** (Ex): Slashing and piercing weapons and electricity attacks deal no damage to an ochre jelly. Instead the creature splits into two identical jellies, **each with half of the original’s current hit points** (round down). A jelly with 10 hit points or less cannot be further split and dies if reduced to 0 it points.

That is a lot weaker: when the jelly splits, each half only has half the hits, not all of them. So my take would be that the scourge's ability is too strong for a 6HD monster, and likely needs to be culled, or adjusted.

However, there is no guidance in the rules how to exactly do that. So this will be a judgment call by the DM.